# Bayesian Network modelling using data driven approach for Information retrieval?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, information-retrieval, bayesian-networks, hierarchical-bayesian

I am exploring the method and code to construct the Bayesian network for information retrieval using a **data-driven approach**. I do find very old papers where the dataset or code are not available. I am new and exploring this field.
Please, if anyone can provide the code link or suggestion of latest papers that can help to give the implementation touch for Bayesian network construction.

Comment: Can you expand on the sources you've already explored? (e.g. [Chapter 11 on Probabilistic Information Retrieval](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/probabilistic-information-retrieval-1.html) from the [Intro Information Retrieval](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html) book?)

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I do have read some research paper on it such as [Evaluation of an Inference Network-Based Retrieval Model](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/125187.125188), [Inference Networks for Document Retrieval](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/96749.98006), and [Building Bayesian network-based information retrieval systems](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=875079). All these do not provide any opensource code to start with. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: It was pretty uncommon to release research code in the 1990s (it's rare now, but it was rare then too).

Comment: A good place to start could be with Naive Bayes on data sets for document classification or retrieval tasks (e.g. [BBC](http://mlg.ucd.ie/datasets/bbc.html)). If you want to look more into structure in networks, [`bnlearn`](https://www.bnlearn.com/) or [`pomegranate`](https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) aim at more general learning/inference.